# Why does the hasOwnProperty alias falsely return undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
function object() {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype = {
        alias: {},
        hasOwnProperty: function() { return false; },
        hasProperty: function(obj, prop) {
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                if (obj[i] !== prop) return false;
                else if (obj[i] === prop) return true;
                else return undefined;
            }
        }
    };
    return new F();
}

var newObj = object();
newObj.alias.msg = "Hello";
console.log(newObj.hasProperty(newObj.alias, "Hello"));
```

It returns undefined for newObj.hasProperty(newObj.alias, "Hello"). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one thing, `alias` is a plain object, and therefore doesn't have a `.length` property that can be used for your `for` loop.

If you place:

```
console.log(i);
```

...in your `for` loop, you'll notice that you never actually run the block.

And even if you fixed the loop, you're still doing a `return` in the very first enumeration, so if the property you're testing isn't first in the loop, you'll get an incorrect result.

Ultimately, you won't be able to replicate the behavior of `hasOwnProperty()` with a loop, because the `prototype` will be included in the enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because you're iterating an object as if you were iterating an array.

The for-loop never loops anything at all, because objects don't have a length property, and aren't indexed by number.

You need to use a for-in loop:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    //key will contain the name of the property, and obj[key] the value
    if(key === blah) ...
}
```